# how to get a common cookie value in deferent sites?

Tags: php, cookies

I have a cookie
cookie_name : debug_flag
cookie_value: 1
cookie_domain : localhost

I have 2 sites with diffrent domain:
www.aaa.com
www.bbb.com

I want to get the common cookie (debug_flag) in these sites using php.
how can I get it?

```
<?php 
    // how to get debug cookie ....
    if($debug_flag){
        echo 'yes'
    }
?>
```

Comment: you cant do it, the cookie is per domain (or all sub domain under main domain), for do something like this you need to store the cookie in a db that this 2 sites can access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not. Cookies are used inside domain only (2-nd level domain) and can not be passed natively (i.e. via cookie logic in browser) from one domain to another. You have to pass your variable via another way, such as GET, for example. Another way is to make your sites (I assume they are both yours) as a subdomains for common domain, i.e.

```
aaa.domain.com
bbb.domain.com
```

-then you will be able to access cookies from one site to another.

Cookie are used per domain for security reason - so to be sure that one site will never access to cookies of another.

Comment: thank you very much. I want to let my sites distinguish whether is my pc or other pc , if cookie cant not do this job , can any way do it ? suc as $_SERVER['XXX']

Comment: As I've said - you have to exchange your data via some common point. It cant be get-parameter (like `http://www.aaa.com?debug_flag=yes`) or, for example, database that is accessible from both sites.

Comment: http://www.aaa.com?debug_flag=yes seems ok, but is dangerous, other people can do it if they know the url

Comment: If it's only for you, just check that address is yours, like `if(isset($_GET['debug_flag']) && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='my-ip-address')` or pass some secret word in addition (in fact, your `debug_flag` could be named more complicated so no one will guess it)